# find the value $\frac{49b^2+39bc+9c^2}{a^2}=52$

Tags: contest-math

Let $a,b.c$ be real numbers such that
$$\begin{cases}a^2+ab+b^2=9\\
b^2+bc+c^2=52\\
c^2+ca+a^2=49
\end{cases}$$

show that
$$\dfrac{49b^2+39bc+9c^2}{a^2}=52$$

I have found this problem solution by geomtry methods.[solution 1](https://s3.amazonaws.com/hmmt-archive/february/2016/solutions/algebra.pdf),can you someone have Algebra methods?

Comment: In [M2](http://habanero.math.cornell.edu:3690) `R=QQ[a,b,c]` `I=ideal(a^2+a*b+b^2-9,b^2+b*c+c^2-52,c^2+c*a+a^2-49)` `(49*b^2+39*b*c+9*c^2-52*a^2)%I -- not 0`

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\begin{cases}a^2+ab+b^2=x\\
b^2+bc+c^2=y\\
c^2+ca+a^2=z
\end{cases}$$

Then 
$$\begin{cases}
(a-c)(a+b+c) = x-y\\
(b-a)(a+b+c) = y-z\\
(c-b)(a+b+c) = z-x\\
\end{cases}$$

Let $(a+b+c)^{-1}=k$, then

$$\begin{cases}
(a-c) = (x-y)k\\
(b-a) = (y-z)k\\
(c-b) = (z-x)k\\
\end{cases}$$